# How to hide a password in an org mode source block?

Tags: org-babel, python

For educational purposes I'm using org-mode to explain some python by exporting to html and the `:exports both` header argument.

```python
pw="mypassword"

def myFunction(apikey)
    print("foo")

myFunction(pw)
```

Is there any way to hide the secret part?

I realize this question might be non-related to org-mode and I'm tempted accessing my https://www.passwordstore.org/ with e.g. https://github.com/xolox/python-qpass

Comment: Make python read the password from a file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to have org-mode automatically obfuscate a password when you export. But, there are a bunch of other things you could do.

One option:

- Create an environment variable for the password using `M-x setenv`
- Then read the value of that environment variable in the python block using `os.environ`